# html how to remove head and tail of tag hr

Tags: html, css

In my html code, it's has `<hr noshade>` tag, it's nothing happens for web view but it's show head and tail when I print it to PDF file like this

[image]

this is my `css` that apply style when print PDF file on `<hr noshade>`

```
 hr{border-color: #000000 !important;  border-top:none !important; height:1px !important;}
```

please help me, I want remove height of head and tail of it to

[image]

thank in advance.

Comment: It may depend on how you create the PDF. What package do you use for it?

Answer (score 2):

Remove all borders except the bottom. You can do something like:

```css
hr{border-color: #000000 !important;  border-width:0 0 1px 0 !important; height:1px !important;}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hr {background: url(bg/dotted-line-repeat.jpg) repeat-x center center;height: 20px;}

hr{background-color:#E5173F;border:medium none;height:1px;margin:20px 100px 0;padding:0;color:#E5173F;}
```

Comment: use any one in above hr css